# simple_form: belongs_to as string in input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to use simple_form to *display* values of a model (as opposed to inputting them).  For my `belongs_to` associations, I simply want a string with the :description property inside a normal read-only input field.  I **don't** want to have a select dropdown in this case since I'm only displaying the value.  I've tried something like

```rb
<%= f.association :matrix,
      label_method: :description,
      as: :string,
      readonly: true %>
```

Which *does* make the field a read-only input, but is putting just the ID of the association (in this case, *matrix_id*) instead of the :description (`my_object.matrix.description`) field.

What am I missing?  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple_form is not made for this behaviour.

Just insert the following field as we dont want it to send in the update action:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= f.object.matrix.description if f.object.matrix %>" readonly>
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks!